# How to configure Sitecore Multiple sites to have separate apppool

Tags: iis-7, sitecore

We have 1 sitecore instance and we have multisite solution . So now is there  a way that we can have separate apppool for each site , so that each site has separate details and one site will not effect another.

Thanks

Comment: someone came and give -2 just for question. Come on i have a doubt thats why i am asking a question , may be it is silly for you but it is of high importance to me.

Comment: Why do you need separate app pools? If you have only one Sitecore running, you should only need one app pool. Multiple app pools won't give you any benefit, since there's only a single application running.

Comment: @JayS we have almost 10 websites which needs to go in Sitecore . So i dont want all website sharing one appool and if one website goes down it will effect all other also.

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason you cannot have 2 AppPools, but it does mean that you will need 2 separate sites in IIS, there is no way to do this from Sitecore. You *could* point both IIS sites to the same codebase as well BUT get ready for clashes, particularly locks on the log files.

Main thing to be aware of is Sitecore licensing. You would have to check but depending on your  license having 2 sites in IIS may well mean 2 Sitecore licenses.

What exactly are you trying to avoid? One site affecting the other how? If you have 2 sites pointing out the same codebase then deployments will cause both to restart. Perhaps if you provide more details on what the issues are then we can provide better suggestions.

Comment: Right now i have 3 websites running in Production with one Sitecore instance using same apppool . So if something happens to one website, is that going to effect the other live websites. Or we can have diffrent apppool for these 3 websites having one instance.

Comment: Yes, this is an issue with having multple sites in one instance but you can't have 3 AppPools for a single instance, the AppPool is set in IIS and only 1 AppPool per site. You could separate but it is a question of licensing, I would check with your sales rep.

Comment: @Sam Not anything extra, sorry. Make sure you are running in 64-bit mode, have LOTS OF RAM and handle your exceptions well! I'm actually interested in how other people deal with this situation too, but unfortunately there have been no other replies :(

Comment: jammykam is right.  Unless you have specifically negotiated something different with Sitecore, each 'IIS Site' is a separate Sitecore license.  I've successfully configured many Sitecore sites to run under a single 'IIS Site' with a single app pool. It comes down to governance and oversight with the separate sites.  You have to make sure you are able to keep tabs on the development efforts of the separate sites to ensure that they aren't stepping on each other's toes.

Comment: As @jammykam mentioned, you're going to get a lot of locks on things like log files.... not to mentioned MediaCache clearing, Lucene indexes, and possibly other areas. Not only could this produce issues on your sites, it will clog up the logs with errors. I recommend against using this approach.